# Is it possible to get the view the .java, .xml, and the image resources in eclipse from an app downloaded in the app market?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I am going through the mybringback android developement [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oz8KG4wwBzA&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=134&feature=plpp_video).

I downloaded the apps we are developing in the series of tutorials from the app market with the name: thenewboston basics

I want to know if I can view the source code for this app in eclipse so I can better learn from the tutorials. Is this possible? If so, how do I do this? If not, do you know of anywhere I can download the source code for the apps made in these tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is full app code uploaded on the site but you can go to [mybringback](http://www.mybringback.com)
 go to Courses->Android New Boston->Go to the third entry.There you can find some code.